# Why the console.log can't write prompt info?

Tags: javascript, console

My test.html ,when object whose id is `submit_botton` clicked, snedData function was triggered.

```
<input type="text" value="test">
<input id="submit_button" type="button" value="submit">
<p id="prompt">test</p>
<script>    
function sendData()
{
    console.log("i am log info");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("post", "write.php",true); 
    xmlHttp.send("q=test"); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){        
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){ 
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}

ob = document.getElementById("submit_button"); 
ob.addEventListener("click",sendData);
</script>
```

`test.php` contains only one line.

```
<?php
echo "haha";
?>
```

Why  `console.log("i am log info ");` can't be activated, no log info in console?
[image]

Comment: I'm curious. Without php does it work? (I tried with no php file and it did work.)

Comment: your code seems fine, you are clicking the button and nothing gets logged? can you provide a stackblitz

Comment: Just copied the html, ran it in Firefox, saw the console.log as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason is that setting in my debug setting for chrome. 
[image]

You can see the hidden tag at the right upper corner.
Remove `xml`,console info shows now.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the script tag: `</script>`

---

*Edit:*

> It is no use to add  tag

The script tag is your problem. Now that you've added the closing script tag, it works. I'm testing in Chrome 70. Click Run below to test it on SO.

If it's not working on your codebase, it is a problem somewhere else outside of the example code you've given.

```js
function sendData()
{
    console.log("i am log info");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("post", "write.php",true);
    xmlHttp.send("q=test");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}

ob = document.getElementById("submit_button");
ob.addEventListener("click",sendData);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test">
<input id="submit_button" type="button" value="submit">
<p id="prompt">test</p>
```

Comment: It is no use to add `</script>` tag, issue remains here,please test in your chrome.

Comment: @scrapy Check out my edit above. Also please don't delete the question again once the answer is correct.

Comment: Please add  test.php and try it again.

Comment: @scrapy SO only allows frontend technologies to run. It doesn't make a difference, the `i am log info` is running and that is your only question.

Comment: So,please try it in your local machine with apache server.

Comment: @scrapy I did, and `i am log info` printed. Is it not printing for you on your local machine? If you're wondering why the `test.php` is working, it's probably because your `xmlHttp.open` is looking for `write.php`

Comment: typo for write.php,in my case it is no use to fix write.php as test.php,i find the reason,debug setting in chrome .